# Python Suds/SOAP exception prefix (ser) not resolved

Tags: python, exception, soap, wsdl, suds

I am trying to use the WSDL web service at https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/case/v2/WebCase?wsdl

Here is the python code I tried to work with :

```
from suds.client import Client
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport.http').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
url = "https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/case/v2/WebCase?wsdl"
client = Client(url)

print client
```

And here is the debug log and exception I am getting

```
DEBUG:suds.wsdl:reading wsdl at: https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/case/v2/WebCase?wsdl ...
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/case/v2/WebCase?wsdl)
DEBUG:suds.metrics:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:tns="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
 <types>
   <xsd:schema>
     <xsd:import namespace="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"  schemaLocation="https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/case/v2/WebCase/_resources_/xsd/WCS_114346525.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
 <message name="RegisterForCloudUIRequest">
   <part element="tns:RegisterForCloudUIRequest" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="RegisterForCloudUIResponse">
   <part element="tns:RegisterForCloudUIResponse" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="AlertOperationRequest">
   <part element="tns:AlertRequest" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="AlertOperationResponse">
   <part element="tns:AlertResponse" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="QueryCaseOperationRequest">
   <part element="tns:QueryCaseRequest" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="QueryCaseOperationResponse">
   <part element="tns:QueryCaseResponse" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="DeviceOperationRequest">
    <part element="tns:DeviceRequest" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <message name="DeviceOperationResponse">
   <part element="tns:DeviceResponse" name="parameters"/>
 </message>
 <portType name="WebCaseService_SOAP11HTTPS_client_Interface">
   <operation name="RegisterForCloudUI">
  <input message="ser:RegisterForCloudUIRequest" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  <output message="ser:RegisterForCloudUIResponse" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="AlertOperation">
  <input message="ser:AlertOperationRequest" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  <output message="ser:AlertOperationResponse" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="QueryCaseOperation">
  <input message="ser:QueryCaseOperationRequest" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  <output message="ser:QueryCaseOperationResponse" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="DeviceOperation">
  <input message="ser:DeviceOperationRequest" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  <output message="ser:DeviceOperationResponse" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/"/>
  </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="WebCaseService_SOAP11HTTPS_client_Binding"  type="ser:WebCaseService_SOAP11HTTPS_client_Interface" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
  <operation name="RegisterForCloudUI">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/RegisterForCloudUI"/>
  <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="AlertOperation">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/AlertOperation"/>
  <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="QueryCaseOperation">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/QueryCaseOperation"/>
  <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="DeviceOperation">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/DeviceOperation"/>
  <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
  </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="WebCaseService_SOAP11HTTPS_client">
  <port name="WebCaseService_SOAP11HTTPS_client" binding="ser:WebCaseService_SOAP11HTTPS_client_Binding" xmlns:ser="http://ph.services.dell.com/Server/">
  <soap:address location="https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/case/v2/WebCase"/>
  </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
sax duration: 9 (ms)
```

Exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
    client = Client(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 207, in resolve
    c.resolve(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 491, in resolve
    qref = qualify(op.input, self.root, definitions.tns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/xsd/__init__.py", line 56, in qualify
    raise Exception('prefix (%s) not resolved' % p)
Exception: prefix (ser) not resolved
```

I have looked at similar questions that triggered "Exception: prefix (**somestring**) not resolved" but I am not able to figure this out from the other solutions. Can anyone help me to get this working ?

Comment: I hard coded the missing resolution into "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/xsd/__init__.py" to get this working, not the right fix but it works.